# Must the dimensions of $V$ and $U$ be equal for $f: U \mapsto V$ to be a diffeomorphism?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose we have $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and a map $f: U \mapsto V$. If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, must the dimensions of $U$ and $V$ be equal?

I'm thinking this is true since the tangent map $Df_{x}: T_{x}U \mapsto T_{f(x)}V$ has to be a linear isomorphism if $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Does your notation mean $V = f(U)$ or $V \supseteq f(U)$?

Comment: Here I mean $V \supset f(U)$ @EricTowers

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the explanation you gave is also the right one.

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then there exists $g\colon V\rightarrow U$ such that $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_{U}$ and using the chain rule:
$$Dg_{f(x)}\circ Df_x=\operatorname{id}_{T_xU},$$
so that $Df_x$ is an invertible linear map.

Answer (score -2):

Let $n=2$, $U$ be the $x$-axis, $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the identity.  Notice $\left. f \right|_U$ is a diffeomorphism $U \rightarrow V$.

Comment: Eric, how is your $f$ a diffeomorphism? Suppose we take $(a,b) \in V$ with $a \neq b$, then the preimage of this point under $f$ is empty @Eric

Comment: I did not downvote, but $f_{\vert U}$ is a diffeomorphism only on its image which has dimension $1$.

Comment: @Alex : As clarified in comments to the Question, OP does not require $f$ to be a surjection onto $V$.  *I*'m used to bijective diffeomorphisms, but I've bumped into others that relax surjectivity.  These guys should use words like homodiffeomorphism and isodiffeomorphism, but they don't.

Comment: You are right, they should really use other words for it; but I am genuinely confused, Alex is the original poster and they seemed to have posted two contradictory comments about their definition of diffeomorphism...

Comment: Your usage of terminology is one I've never seen in 40 years as a practicing differential geometer and algebraic geometer. A diffeomorphism is a smooth map with a smooth inverse; in particular, it is a bijection.

Comment: I agree that Eric's usage is non-standard, but he is just echoing the usage of the original poster.  I would say that I *have* seen the usage of the OP, but clarified as $f:U\rightarrow V$ is a difeomorphism *onto its image*.  I agree that a naked "f is a diffeomorphism" has the meaning Ted suggests.

Comment: @TedShifrin : I'm generally with you, but OP seems to go the other way.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the comments. I truly believe the OP is confused.

Comment: @TedShifrin : I asked for clarification in comment to the Question.  It was clarified by OP.